# Is it possible to detect if an application is running on the user's computer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension for myself where it would block sensitive information (such as logins, personal info, etc) when OBS (a streaming and recording program) is running on the computer. Is it possible to detect if OBS is running on the user's computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only Javascript and in-browser the answer is no, because of security reasons.

But there are various frameworks like Node.js that can help.